# permissionエラーによりpostgresqlの起動ができません

Tags: postgresql, heroku

## 概要

初心者・初投稿です。
herokuで個人作成アプリを本番環境にあげるため、postgresqlをインストールしました。
起動してみたところ、以下のエラーが表示されました。

```
 % psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.2  ##導入確認

 % brew services start postgresql  ##postgresqlの起動
Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/{username}/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

## 試したこと・仮説

管理者権限に問題があると思い、以下のことを行いました。

```
% cd /Users/{username}/Library/LaunchAgents/   ##記載されていたパスへ移動

% ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 root            staff    96  3 12  2019 .
drwx------@ 79 {username}      staff  2528  2 29 10:37 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root            staff   612  3 12  2019 com.adobe.GC.Invoker-1.0.plist

% sudo chown -R Username  ##権限をユーザーネームに変更
% usage: chown [-fhnv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
       chown [-fhnv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...
```

このようになり、権限は変更されませんでした。
プログラミング自体初心者なもので、権限に関することはさっぱりです。
お詳しい方、何卒ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちら、Heroku にアップロードする前に手元の Mac に postgresql をインストールしようとされている、という状況で間違いないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ファイルの権限を無理やりユーザーに変更するのはまずいんじゃないでしょうか。
実際にやったわけではないのですが、サービス起動をsudoで行うとうまくいきませんか？

```
 % sudo brew services start postgresql  ##postgresqlの起動
```

ちなみにchownが失敗しているのは、権限を変更する対象のファイル(もしくはディレクトリ)を指定していないからです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！！
無理やりユーザに変更するのはまずいことだったんですね。。。
先ほどファイルの権限を変更できsqlが起動したのですが、戻してsudoつけてやってみたいと思います。
すみませんが、権限を元に戻す方法をご存知でしたら教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 権限をつけてしまったのであれば、元の状態に戻すと言っても、もう一度chownを使って元の状態に書き戻すくらいしか私には判りません。現時点で開発環境として問題なく動いている、もしくはご自身のユーザでしか実行しないのであれば、とりあえずはそのまま進めることもありかもしれません。

Comment: そうなんですね、不安だったので助かりました。ご丁寧に説明していただきありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

着眼点は大きくハズレてはいないと思います。

■起動コマンド
herokuは名前しか知りませんが、これでイケませんか？

```
subdo brew services start postgresql
```

■対処について
他回答でも指摘していますが、権限関係はあるべき状態になっているものなので、それ自体を弄るのは正しい作法ではありません。ただ、状況から考えて「取り敢えず動く状態にする」というのはあながち間違いでもありません。（※動いた後で「あるべき状態」を忘れると、未来で泣きを見ますが）

コマンドエラーについてはエラー内容を確認してください。

```
% usage: chown [-fhnv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
       chown [-fhnv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...
```

よく見ると末尾に「file」と指摘されていることが分かります。
タイプミスなどでエラーはよく見るものなので、メッセージの意味とか「man コマンド」は少しずつ慣れてください。